# What's the relationship of @material-ui/core and @types/material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, npm-install

Here I see an example project using material-ui.

I see I have the following packages inside of package.json file

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.1",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.20.6",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

After the `npm install`, I see the following directories in my project folder

```
node_modules/@types/material-ui/
node_modules/@material-ui/core/
```

Here are my questions:

1. I wanted to understand why material-ui uses `@` as part of its package name, is it true that this kind of package naming means it's a TS package? i.e., it itself carries the type information.
2. If the above is true, is it true that `/@types/material-ui/` is not needed at all?

Answer (score 12):

`@` in the package name doesn't mean it is a TypeScript package; plain JavaScript packages can also have the `@` prefix.

The `@` prefix means this is a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages); i.e. there is a family of packages under `@material-ui/` as well as under `@types/`.

In this specific case, `@material-ui/core` contains its own type definitions (`*.d.ts` files), so `@types/material-ui` is not needed and will not actually be used.  In general `@types/` packages are needed for plain JavaScript packages which do not contain any type definitions on their own.

Comment: It looks like we don't need the @types/material-ui according to https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/, am I missing anything?

Comment: @chen you don't need it... but I had to bump tsconfig es5 to es6

Comment: He says we dont need to install like `npm i -D @types/material-ui` 'cause material-ui has already types definition in its package.

Answer (score 0):

`@types` modules are used by TypeScript to provide you with rich type definitions of methods and members. If you're using TypeScript, keep them, otherwise there's no need.

Read more here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/@types.html

Answer (score 0):

Packages starting with `@` are a convention for "scoping" them. It's awesome: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

The `@types` scope is TypeScript type definitions provided by the huge [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) project